# Set Digital Timer in dataTable row

Tags: jquery

```
var buttonCancel = '<button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-12 button-cancel">Cancel</button>'; 
function UpdateDataSet(data){
  if(data != '' && data != undefined){
      data = data.map(function (obj) {
         var ds = timer();
         if (!obj)
         return;
         obj.push(ds,buttonCancel);
         return obj;
      });
  }
  if (dispatchTable) {
    dispatchTable.fnDestroy();
  }
  dispatchTable = $('#table-dispatch').dataTable({
    "data": data,
    "columnDefs": [
        {"sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [9]},
        {"sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [10]},
    ]
  });
}
```

I use jquery.dataTables.js and i have added digital timer after the dataTable last row of td.
the data and obj is coming from socket like that.

```
data = ['1','Waiting for pickup','test','9826','Apr 25, 2016 4:35 PM','akhil1 04','NaN','Thaltej ,Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380054, India','0$','0','0'] ;
obj = [1, "Waiting for pickup", "test", "9826", "Apr 25, 2016 4:35 PM", "akhil1 04", NaN, "Thaltej, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380054, India", "0$", 0, 0];
```

i push cancal button with time in object. this timer() function.

```
var digiclock = "00:00:00";
i = 0;
function timer() {
   var digiformat = "";
   if (i > 3599) {
      var H = Math.floor(i / 3600);
   }else {
      var H = 0;
   }

   var M = i - (H * 3600)
   if (M > 59) {
      M = Math.floor(M / 60)
   }else {
      M = 0
   }

   var S = i - (M * 60)
   if (H < 10) {
      H = "0" + H;
   }

   if (M < 10) {
      M = "0" + M;
   }

   if (S < 10) {
      S = "0" + S;
   }

  var result = H + ":" + M + ":" + S;
  return result;
  setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
  i++;
}
```

can you help me how to add timer in dataTable row of td.its display time when record store in dataTable.but its take one time then timer is stop not to increment timer.

[In Image where timer is stop on time  field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJhoJ.png)
so pls help me. how to add timer in dataTable.
In advance thanks....

Comment: pls anyone can help me......